# Apple Logo Emoji - Colors or Original Apple Rainbow Equivalent

Tags: html, css, unicode

Is the apple Unicode char logo,  available in other colors or the original rainbow Apple logo?

Realize  displays as black and white glyph but looking for any alternative equivalent (to display as a solid color or rainbow Apple) other than a basic image on an HTML page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the apple Unicode char logo,  available in other colors...?
> Realize  displays as black and white glyph...

It's not clear to me how you reached the conclusion that the display color of the  can't be modified. By nature of being a glyph, the  can be styled as any text might be:

```css
body {
  font-size: 36px;
}

#red {
  color: red;
}

#yellow {
  color: yellow;
}

#green {
  color: green;
}

#white {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<span id></span>
<span id="red"></span>
<span id="yellow"></span>
<span id="green"></span>
<span id="white"></span>
```

> ... looking for any alternative equivalent (to display as[...] rainbow Apple)...

This is a bit trickier to accomplish with full support of all user agents, but you can get pretty good results using the appropriate vendor prefixes for things like `background-clip` and `text-fill-color`:

```css
body {
  font-size: 36px;
}

#rainbow {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#5EBD3E 0% 32%, #FFB900 32% 41.5%, #F78200 41.5% 51%, #E23838 51% 60.5%, #973999 60.5% 70%, #009CDF 70% 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<span id="rainbow"></span>
```

In the example above I've done a bit of free-handing to visually match closely with the original Apple "rainbow logo" coloring; if exact replication of the color stop positions is important to you, you might wish to tweak them a bit.

**It is important to note, however** that support for styling with these attributes is not universal, and you should have a fallback plan for users without compatible user agents. See [Can I use... "`text-fill-color`"](https://caniuse.com/?search=text-fill-color) and [Can I use... "`background-clip`"](https://caniuse.com/?search=background-clip) for more information in making your determination if the trade-offs are acceptable considering your userbase.

Answer (score 0):

Check out feather icons & font awesome icons. If neither of those have it look to react-icons

Comment: This does not address the OP's core question of changing the presentation color of a built-in Unicode glyph.

Comment: Well that may be true. It does solve the problem of getting the Apple icon in colors and also has the added benefit of maybe teaching someone who doesn't know that there are other icon libraries available a new tool that he can use.